# error: ** server can't find xx.xx.xxx.xxx.in-addr.arpa: REFUSED

Tags: 16.04, networking, dns

I am preparing my DNS configuration. When I checked:

```
nslookup [dns name]
```

it shows an error:

> error: ** server can't find xx.xx.xxx.xxx.in-addr.arpa: REFUSED

Where did I do wrong?

Comment: Which DNS-server are you using?

Comment: Try to add`empty-zones-enable no;` in your `named.conf.options`

Comment: @vidarlo did you mean the server provider's information? I am using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS 64 bit server machine. Is this related to server category?

Comment: @Mitch I am not so expert on these configuring issues. Would you please explain what will happen if I follow your instruction? Did you find any reason why it should be changed? I am extra sensitive to these changes. If something goes wrong it will make server unstable.

Comment: Take a look [Here](http://www.zytrax.com/books/dns/ch7/queries.html#empty-zones-enable).

Comment: `nslookup` syntax is `nslookup - DNS_SERVER_HERE` and then you can run queries inside it.  Alternatively, `nslookup google.com` or such is how you would do a DNS search specifically.  If you simply put an IP address in, it'll try to get a PTR address which likely isn't what you're after.